# Where do I place code to log successful file creation?

Tags: c#, logging

In the code below, .GenerateFile() returns a stream. This is WCF service which, given user parameters, streams a file back to the user's browser. A webforms app runs in the browser and the WCF service is called server-side.

The question, where do I place code to log successful attempts to generate a file? If I place the logging code above the call to .GenerateFile(), there is no guarantee of success. If successful, this method is done (the return keyword). What should I do?

```
    // Other stuff in method
    .
    .
    .
    try
    {
        return this.GenerateFile(xyz1, xyz2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Msg.SendException(ex);

        Logger.LogException(ex);

        return null;
    }
} // End of Method
```

Comment: Assign to a variable, log the message, then return the variable.

Comment: Some of these files returned by the stream are 100+ MB. Are you saying store the stream in a variable, log, and then return the variable containing the stream contents?

Comment: See Nick's answer. You're not storing the contents, just the stream that `GenerateFile` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the result of GenerateFile in a variable, log the success then return the stored result.

```
try
{
    var result = this.GenerateFile(xyz1, xyz2);
    Log("success");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was using a stream to avoid putting the entire file in memory. Isn't that what this code does? Am I in for trouble with larger files?

Comment: The stream doesn't actually store the contents of a file, just information about how to access it.  Also, I'm pretty sure stream is a reference type, so either way would only ever create one instance of the stream in memory.

Comment: Interesting. I'll do some more research on streams. Thanks!